# z-index in absolute position not working in datepicker bootsraps

Tags: css, bootstrap-timepicker

I have question is that possible if `absolute` position move in front of `absolute` position too using `z-index`? like my problem below here :

[image: Time Picker Using Bootstraps datepicker from eonasdan]

so i using timepicker, as we can see on the red arrow is timepicker with css i made like this :

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom {
        position: absolute !important;
        z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

and on the blue arrow is a div with position `absolute`, and as you can see in the image, timepicker position is behind `div` on the blue arrow even though I already set `z-index: 9999 !important;`, The timepicker will be on the front of `div` if i change position `div` on the blue arrow into `relative`, but the problem is i can't change position on `div` from `absolute` to `relative` because for several reasons, is there any other way to make that timepicker in front of div with `absolute` position?

Comment: Can you share the full code to look into? and you don't have to use 9999 if you use z-index correctly.

Comment: Use negative z-index

Comment: @Vaibhav use negative z-index? Is not that using negative z-index make element going to behind?

Comment: @Manjuboyz i loved to, but the code is to long and i using easyui panel, so the css will be on the easyui plugins, what should i use for z-index?

Comment: Use negative z-index for your element which is relative

Comment: @Vaibhav it's still doesn't work